Accessing Digital Ocean Postgress db
So I have a webapp hosted on DO using their github feature, and an attached postgress db. The website was delpoyed and is visible, but there's a problem with the db saying one of the tables doesn't exits so I need to give it a look but don't know how.
I saw that some people use DBeaver to acces databases, and I put the credentials in but it's giving me an error saying that the Connection attempt timed out. One thing that I was unsure of when connecting was the sslmode, becasue DO has it as required, but I can't seem to find what type of certificate and what keys to use.
If there are ways to acces and see the db other than DBeaver that are easier I'm all ears, if not how can I get the SSL information needed
